# Rails: Validating a Date Greater than Another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

I'm writing a custom validator in ActiveRecord so that a deadline makes sense:

```
  validate :deadline_is_possible?

  def deadline_is_possible?
    if deadline > begins_at
      errors.add(:deadline, 'must be possible')
    end
  end
```

This however generates a "NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass". I event tried to turn the dates into strings, like:

```
  def deadline_is_possible?
    if deadline.to_s > begins_at.to_s
      errors.add(:deadline, 'must be possible')
    end
  end
```

and though it doesn't generate an error, doesn't work either.

I also declared other validators (such as

```
  def begins_at_is_date?
    if !begins_at.is_a?(Date)
      errors.add(:begins_at, 'must be a date')
    end
  end
```

that work OK.

Answer (score 14):

You can use comparison:

```rb
   validates :deadline, comparison: { greater_than: :begins_at }
```

Doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison

Comment: This only present on Rails 7... :-/

Answer (score 11):

You likely need to handle if one of the dates is nil. You can either set these to have a default value in the deadline database, or do something like:

```
  validate :deadline_is_possible?

  def deadline_is_possible?
    return if [deadline.blank?, begins_at.blank?].any?
    if deadline > begins_at
      errors.add(:deadline, 'must be possible')
    end
  end
```

Comment: This removes the error, however it does not work as expected:

    `@event.deadline=@event.begins_at+1.day;`
    `@event.should_not be_valid`

returns valid...
should I pick a more specific gem to do the job?

Comment: I correct myself: the above code works, whereas this doesn't:

    `@event.deadline=@event.begins_at;`
    `@event.should be_valid`

returns NOT valid...

Comment: That could be misleading... would you try `@event.deadline=@event.begins_at; @event.should have(0).errors_on(:deadline) `

Comment: In the end, I used the timeliness Gem, and everything worked smoothly

Answer (score 9):

You can add your own validator:

```
class AfterDateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if value.blank?

    other_date = record.public_send(options.fetch(:with))

    return if other_date.blank?

    if value < other_date
      record.errors.add(attribute, (options[:message] || "must be after #{options[:with].to_s.humanize}"))
    end
  end
end
```

And use it in a model:

```
validates :invited_on, presence: true
validates :selected_on, presence: true, after_date: :invited_on
```